# How to pass https traffic through a Windows VM?

Tags: windows, networking, virtual-machine, vpn

I have a project, and to run it I need to access the url `https://example.com` and in order to access that url, I need a vpn connection. When I start the vpn connection, I loose contact with the rest of the internet, which is not desirable.

But I already have a VM that is using the same vpn for other purposes. I can access the url inside that machine. So I thought that I maybe could route the traffic through the virtual machine, and then just edit the hosts file to `<ip of VM> example.com`? But tbh, I'm not sure if I'm on the right track here.

Both host and VM is running Windows 10, and I'm using Hyper-V for virtualization.

How can I achieve this? Or am I even on the right track?

Comment: If the VPN allows local connections you could run a HTTP proxy in that VM and specify that proxy in your web browser outside. Before doing so please check the policy of your company regarding VPN, usually forwarding traffic from an internal network (VPN) to an external device is prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the VPN client is routing all traffic via the link.
Depending on the type, you should be able to route only specific addresses via the tunnel, and send all other traffic via the default gateway.
In Windows, you can open the Properties for the tunnel adapter, Network tab, TCP/IPv4 Properties, Advanced, IP Settings. Disable the checkbox 'Use default gateway on remote network'.

[Advanced TCP/IP Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgr7S.png)